# How to fix screen resume or list commands on Ubuntu system?

Tags: gnu-screen

Screen or GNU Screen is a terminal multiplexer.See [this](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/) for more information.
Somehow the screen command has been messed up accessing a remote server. I'm still able to start a new screen (screen <"enter">) but screen -list or screen -r is not working anymore so I am unable to resume existing screens. I don't have the sudo privileges to reinstall/update the utility.

Answer (score 0):

All it took was to delete the screen sessions as present in  `/var/run/screen` folder:
`rm /var/run/screen/S-<uname>/*` substituting uname for your username.